# ASIHTTPRequest delegation

Tags: ios, soap, asihttprequest, exc-bad-access

im using ASIHTTPRequest to call webservice (soap):

```
-(void)callWebService:(NSString*)URL:(NSString*)SOAP{

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:URL];
    NSString *SOAPMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:SOAP];
    ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];

    request.shouldAttemptPersistentConnection = NO;
    [request setValidatesSecureCertificate:NO];
    [request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];

    [request appendPostData:[SOAPMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestCompleted:)];
    [request setDidFailSelector:@selector(requestFailed:)];

    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request startAsynchronous];

}

-(void)requestCompleted:(ASIHTTPRequest * )r{

    NSString *responseString = [r responseString];
    NSLog(@"%@",responseString);

}

-(void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest * )r{

    NSError *Err = [r error];
    NSLog(@"%@",Err);

}
```

If i call this in appDelegate.m, it works fine, requestCompleted handler throws the response...But when i use this same code in my own class it throws BAD ACCESS error, which i figured tells me i cannot delegate:self to handle response. if i setDelegate to appdelgate pointer (passed as ID sender) it works (and have handlers there). So why cant my own class handle its own events ? Im new to objective-c so i guess im missing something major here. Thanks

Comment: can you post your class's .h file where you find BAD access please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to have the requestCompleted and requestFailed in your "own class". Also that class has to live which means it can't be released while the service is being called. You have to save the instance of "your own class" in a strong/retained property or something.

Comment: Of course those methods are in the same class. Thanks for strong property advice, i checked and instance is not being released anymore. but somehow the requestCompleted and requestFailed methods are still not being called.

Comment: You still getting bad access or are they just not being called at all? have you set breakpoints in them?

Comment: bad access is solved since instance is not being released. Methods are being called now, i just restarted xcode and it works ( i've had breakpoints on these methods since start). I have no idea, why that happened, anyway, thanks for strong property advice. i still have alot to learn about objective-c :)

Comment: Sounds like you got juked by Xcode. These problems are well chronicled here: http://www.textfromxcode.com/

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to dealloc or viewWillDisappear

```
[request setDelegate:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if your `self` is getting released while the `delegate` call happens. Make sure it is retained properly.

Comment: Thanks for reply, its already solved. Problem was that i had a weak reference on object, so it was released while handler was being called :)